# Extract text blocks with Python + NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, text-extraction

I'm looking for a way to extract text blocks by recognizing patterns with Python and NLTK.

I have the text below and need extract the corresponding text of the question and each alternative.

```
QUESTION 01
For a p-type semiconductor, which of the following statements is true?
A Holes are the majority carriers and pentavalent atoms are the dopants.
B Electrons are the majority carriers and pentavalents atms are the dopants.
C Electrons are the majority carriers and trivalent atoms are the dopants.
```

The best way to do it is with a sort of patterns to the "Question" entity and other patterns to the "Alternative" entity?

Comment: If the answers are consistently marked (A, B, C), you can use a regex to match and split on that pattern.